# Why has the reason behind killing of women not been mentioned in the film?

Tags: character, the-frozen-ground

The American film *[The Frozen Ground](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Frozen_Ground)* was based upon the real life story of [Robert Hansen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Hansen), who used to kill women. But, the psychology behind his criminal activities has not been mentioned in this film.

Why has the reason behind the killing of women not been mentioned in the film?